# Prevent special characters from rendering in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, special-characters

I am forming a curl command from the API response i received. The issue is that the response may contain special characters like '\n', '\u0012', '\t'.
For example if the response contains:

```js
body: "\n\u0012xyz@gmail.com"
```

But on UI the unicode and line break characters are getting rendered:

```js
<!--------line break is occurring ------>
.xyz@gmail.com
```

I am using angularjs as framework. Can anyone tell me how can i prevent these special characters from getting rendered on UI. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `\u0012` coming from in the first place? That's not a legal character in an e-mail address, which suggests your web-service is not sanitizing user-input correctly. If so, then you must fix that first, otherwise you're very likely opening yourself up to XSS attacks or worse.

Comment: @Dai Yeah you are right. But the response is also correct, is supposed to be there.

Comment: Use `String.prototype.trim()` in JS to trim leading and trailing whitespace chars, including `\n` (the `\u0012` is just `LF`, so you actually have `LFCR` aka `\n\r` - which is incorrect: it should be `CRLF` aka `\r\n`. Or you can control how whitespace in DOM text nodes is handled with CSS.